# ZombieJS Wait for page to say data is loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, zombie.js

I am using ZombieJS to test the Jasmine specs and I wrote a Console reporter for Jasmine to use in browser. Below is my code.

var Browser = require("zombie");

```
    var browser = Browser.create();

    //browser.silent = true;
    //browser.debug = false;

    var closeIt = false;

    browser.visit(file, function () {
        browser.wait(function() {
            return (closeIt === true);
        });
    });

    browser.on('console', function (type, data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        closeIt = (parseEvents(data[0], data[1]));
    }); 

    function parseEvents(name, data) {
        return (name === "jasmine.jasmineDone");
    }
```

But this is not working. Page is automatically closed after few of the specs executed. How can set wait to browser to wait till all specs executed.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you need to pass in a callback as a second argument to `browser.wait`.

In that do `browser.close`